# Jquery UI draggable element from fixed div hidden by absolute element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using Jquery UI to drag a div. This div is inside another element with the position fixed. When I drag the element over another div with the position absolute, the dragged element is hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/sGCWZ/

HTML

```
<div style="position: fixed">
    <div id="drag">Drag Me</div>
</div>
<div id="drop">Move here</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#drag").draggable({ 
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#drop{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #999;
}

#drag{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #F00;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

How to keep the dragged div over the absolute div?

Comment: It doesn't appear to happen on FF 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a high z-index to the fixed element.

```
 <div style="position:fixed; z-index:1000000;">
   <!-- code -->
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGCWZ/1/)

Comment: OMG, I tried everything but not this! I am so confused. But thanks it work now...